# How can I set a real phone as default target in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

What I want is: when I press the Run/Debug button it automatically installs and runs on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

From left pane that displays project names,Right click and choose Run As->Run Configurations
In Run Configurations dialog,it should display three tabs named Android,Target and Common.
Choose the tab labeled as Target.
from it choose the radio button Automatically pick compatible device and select your device from the list.
Then mark the check box right below the list named Use same device for future launches.
you are all set.

Or you can choose from the run dialog which prompts you to choose device,mark the checkbox for use same device for future launches here.

Hope this helps